# Visual studio 2015 - Azure Mobile Service project template not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, azure-mobile-services

I can't find Azure Mobile Service Project template in my visual studio 2015 express edition. And I have just updated the Azure SDK to 2.8.1 but still not getting the template. I can see the azure mobile app template so is it the same one?

[Screenshot of vs2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYcUP.png)

please help me !!

Thanks,
Ravi.

Comment: At this point, you should be creating an Azure App Service Mobile App - use the Azure Mobile App template and create an App Service.  Consider Azure Mobile Services as v1 capabilities and Azure App Service Mobile Apps as v2 capabilities.

Comment: So do you mean that my Azure Mobile App will work like a Azure Mobile Service? If yes then does it need any nuget packages or other require configuration in Azure Mobile App project to work like a Azure Mobile Services?

Comment: YEs - Azure Mobile Apps work like Azure Mobile Services.  Yes, there are different version of NuGet.  Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk or the tutorials on the azure.com site for examples.

Answer (score 5):

You may resolve this issue by re-installing/Update the setup.

Restart the setup for VirtualStudio2015. Preview and select the required components to install.

After this you may see everything you want. You know, it's always better to select the features under 'Optional features to install' if you want to get what you want.

Comment: It will reset all my default settings and history data as well as takes time to reinstall it.